# Creating an object of type "derived class"

Tags: c#, inheritance, derived-class

I've been studying class inheritance recently and I keep coming across this specific piece of code.

```
public class Foo {      

 public bool DoSomething() 
 { 
   return false; 
 } 
}  

public class Bar : Foo { 

 public new bool DoSomething() 
 { 
   return true; 
 } 
}  

 public cass Test { 

  public static void Main () {   

    Foo test = new Bar (); 

    Console.WriteLine (test.DoSomething ());     
  } 
}
```

What confuses me here is that, if it were me I would create an instance of Bar by type Bar...

```
Bar test = new Bar();
```

I don't understand why it would be created the way it is in the code.

Comment: The answer you seek lies somewhere in the mix of BrokenGlass's answer and Justin's answer mixed with polymorphism.  Unfortunately, there is no simple answer to such semantics.  You need to familiarize yourself with Factory Patterns, IoC or Dependency Injection.  Factory Pattern is probably the easiest one.  Without experience, you need a book to break down the complex details.  Head First Design Patterns is an excellent choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code was probably written to demonstrate the difference between *overriding* and *hiding* a base class method:

In this case instantiating a `Bar` object using a `Foo` variable will use the base class method `DoSomething()`  and print out `false`. Had the `DoSomething` method been declared as virtual in the base class and been overridden in the derived class the output would be `true` as in the following example:

```
public class Foo {      

 public virtual bool DoSomething() 
 { 
   return false; 
 } 
}  

public class Bar : Foo { 

 public override bool DoSomething() 
 { 
   return true; 
 } 
}
```

Comment: I know the purpose of the code, but what I don't understand is the use of the super class as a reference when creating an instance of a subclass. Is there really any benefit and would it be any different if the super class method was virtual?

Comment: most other answers dive into the benefits of using a base class (and or interface) instead of a concrete class - what it comes down to you want to depend on an abstraction instead of something concrete so you can change out the actual implementation later on - this is the basis of polymorphism and makes such things as IoC / Depedency Injection much more powerful

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to think of these things in real world objects.

Try thinking about a car. You can have different makes/models of car but each car performs the same base functionality.

Your code can work with objects in the same way. You write the code to work with any car, but you can really specify any make/model of car you want:

```
public class Car
{
    public virtual void Drive()
    {
    }
}

public class ChevyVolt : Car
{
    public override void Drive()
    {
        // Initialize the battery and go
    }
}

public class CadillacEscalade : Car
{
    public override void Drive()
    {
        // Check to ensure you have an oil field worth of gas and go
    }
}
```

Now, with those definitions...you could create a class responsible for driving the car. It wouldn't matter what car. You just have to worry about driving:

```
public class Commuter
{
    public void GoToWork()
    {
        // Garage.PickCar() could return either ChevyVolt or an Escalade
        Car todaysRide = Garage.PickCar();

        // Now that we have a car, go to work
        todaysRide.Drive();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it wouldn't be. A more realistic example would be

```
void DoSomethingWithAFoo(Foo f) {
    f.DoSomething();
}
```

In this case, `f` could be a `Foo` or a `Bar`, and `DoSomethingWithAFoo` doesn't have to know or care.

Answer (score 0):

`Bar` derives from `Foo`, and so it is perfectly valid to create an instance of `Bar` and assigned to a a `Foo`-reference.  I suspect the example code that you have shown is merely showing that `Bar` is a `Foo` and is therefore assignable.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a more generic (Foo) with a less generic type ( Boo ) this is usually done when you leverage the polymorphism. The classical example is having Animal, Dod and Cat and then you can say `Animal=new Dog()` or `Animal=new Cat()`, then you can call virtual function on it and having the proper function automatically called. This Is not your case since you are overlapping the function DoSomething with new ...

Answer (score 0):

If you consider that it only wants the functionality defined by `Foo` that `Bar` implements, it might make more sense.  `Bar` is free to add more functionality related to whatever `Bar` is.

```
public class Bar : Foo { 

 public new bool DoSomething() 
 { 
   return true; 
 } 

 public bool IsValid {get;}
}
```

Now the calling code only cares about the abstraction defined by `Foo` so, despite the fact you are creating `Bar`, you *only* get the contract defined by `Foo` (just `DoSomething`) and therefore not `Bar.IsValid` functionality I just defined.